# PHP . execute code only once at all ,

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP and just started to learn it. There is this problem that I'm working on it for quite a time now but nothing seems to work.
well, the problem is that I have a piece of code for a web page and I need it to be executed only once. By that I mean the code must be executed when the very first client views the webpage and stop working for the second and other clients who view the page.
I have tried "include" and "required once" but these execute code once per run. I have also tried using session but it this case also the code executes once for each client.
And Also, yes I know I can use a flag and check database to make this work, but I wanna know that PHP has it handled or not
So I'm kinda stuck here.

We know that PHP is the server side language; therefore does it have any feature which executes a code once and stores the results in its global space?

Here is my code, I read data from excel and then I create my array of items.

```
// foreach row
// I read $col1 ..$col6 from excel for each row
new itemdata($col1,$col2,$col3,$col4,$col5,$col6);


class itemdata
{
    public $item;
    public $cat;
    public $unit;
    public $prec;
    public $alarmType;
    public $order;
    static $items=array();

    function __construct($item,$cat,$unit,$prec,$alarm,$order)
    {
        $this->item = $item ;
        $this->cat = $cat;
        $this->unit = $unit;
        $this->prec = $prec ;
        $this->alarmType = $alarm;
        $this->order = $order;

        array_push(self::$items,$this);
    }
// And some methods for searching declared array 'items'
```

I need to execute this code once at all .
I appreciate your help.

Comment: First, if you find yourself in a situation where you only want to run a piece of code once **ever**, your design pattern is probably incorrect.  Use some sort of persistent data e.g. a file or database entry.  Second, this code doesn't actually do anything aside from declare a class.  The line at the top does literally nothing.

Comment: Clarify your meaning. A new PHP instance runs for each request. Do you want it to run once per request or forever? If the prior, use `require_once`, if the latter, use a file or database entry.

Comment: I fully agree with @LukePark But if you want to run a code only once and then never again: The easy way? Run it yourself and delete the code. The hard way? Include some PHP code that deletes the PHP file after use. Make sure to change your code that it checks if the file exists before calling it though. Otherwise you'll get an error

Comment: `require_once` will require the file to be loaded once per file. If you just `require` you can have it multiple times per page, but `require_once` is just a single time. But it will be included for every request.

Comment: No, you will either need to set a flag if the file has been run or not - or you can delete it altogether if you don't care if it exists after its first execution.

Comment: @Qirel i need to access my static array every time i want , like having some data in Memory which should be initialzed only once , not per each request. and deleting the file will not work for this.

Comment: You don't. You can't have it both ways. Your PHP code needs to "know" it has been run before one way or another. If deleting the code isn't option, you'll need some other resource to verify if the code was executed before or not. Be it a database or some text file or even an ini file.

Comment: It's simple. Query the database. If it returns 0, run the code and update it to 1. Then something along the lines of `if(queryResults > 0){ // instantiate class } else { // dont }`

Comment: But as we said before. Your code is definitely a design flaw. Because how are you planning to access the static array after the page is refreshed? The old result will be destroyed and is gone forever.

Comment: U mean to use database record  as flag . OK , i can use my static array on next requests ? I know the data will be not be in memory for next time

Comment: #icecub i am mentioning this in all my replies but no one cares :D ,  i need persistant data for this code.

Comment: yeah its my design flow at all i know , but I think its php disadvantage , as i used to be java developer and i have some memory that i can work with that.

Comment: It's not about PHP at all, this is how websites work in general. You should learn the basic workflow and not try to apply your knowledge from programming windows/linux applications. It's very different in many aspects.

Comment: The Web is StateLess. That really says it all.